# How to create a resizable rectangle with user touch events on google map Android?

Tags: java, android, overlay, touch-event, android-framelayout

I am beginner in google map. I want to Draw rectangle with choosing the top left and bottom right coordinates on google map. can anyone provide me example to work with.?

Thanks in advance

Comment: someone please answer my question

Answer (score 0):

If you have the top left and bottom right, you can find top right and bottom left too.

If you don't know how to do that, try to understand how Lattitude and Longitude works. This is essential to Maps Programming.

[Android LatLng](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html)

From then on, you need to add these LatLng you have to a PolylineOptions.

[Android Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes?hl=TR)

Good luck.

Edit:

OnMapLongClickListener Catches the event of Long Click on a Google Map.
The below function is going to a marker to anywhere you long click on the map.

```
map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng position) {

                try {

                    MarkerOptions o = new MarkerOptions();

                    o.title("Title");
                    o.snippet("Snippet");
                    o.position(position);

                    Marker addedMarker = map.addMarker(o);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    NLog.e(LOG_ERROR_TAG, e);
                }

            }
        });
```

You can add your markers in a `List<Marker>` and access them later on, for finding the positions (LatLng) of your added markers.

Comment: i have work with longitude and latitude. but the problem is ,i cannot able to work with touch event and map listener event. can you post some code?

Comment: here is my code.. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954209/android-expand-and-shrink-circle-on-google-map"

Comment: Ah that question, I've been following your question as I need to do something similar to what you want to do but I'm sorry, I can't help you about about resizing the circle with touch gestures.

If I find something, I'll let you know.